# Relative path in include-path and library-path

Tags: c++

after compiling my C++ program using g++ in verbose mode, I noticed that the LIBRARY_PATH has many ../

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/../lib/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../
/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

Some of them are interesting like /lib/../lib/. The same is true under mingw environment:

```
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/lib
```

which is a longer version of `d:\mingw\mingw32\lib`, I guess. Why library paths are listed this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When gcc is compiled, much like many other programs using autoconfig, the installation path is specified for it to use. Since gcc has many many files scattered all over the file system, and since compiling gcc is considered a difficult task (which is no longer as true as it used to be, but still), then gcc has a few tricks to reduce the dependency on exact installation path.

What you are seeing is one such trick in action.

By using paths that are relative to the location where a known component resides, gcc created an environment where you can move the entire install base to a different directory and still have it find all of its libraries.